# Spring Boot Repository of an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there any possibility of creating a repository based on an interface in Spring Boot Data?
I made this code, in which Medicamento is an interface that many models implements it, but it didn't work out:

```
public interface MedicamentoRepository extends JpaRepository<Medicamento, Long> {
    public <T extends Medicamento> List<Medicamento> findItens(Class<T> type);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you make `Medicamento` an abstract class?

Comment: Sure, if the automagic repo generation from repo interface is broken for you use case, just create a custom repository.

Comment: Is a Spring Boot app, your interface should work just fine without the `findItens` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Spring Data JPA, Spring is responsible for generating the implementation and register it as a Spring managed component. All you have to do is configure it properly by adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` on your Spring configuration class and specifying the package where are your repository interfaces.

All the basic methods like `findOne`, `findAll`, `delete`, ... are already provided by the `CrudRepository` interface (and `JpaRepository`), so you don't need to add them in your interface.

If you need to add specific methods, then Spring will generate the implementation based on the name of your method and parameters (like `findByName` where `name` is a field of your entity) or using the `@Query` annotation.

For a better understanding of how Spring Data JPA works and all the available features, check their doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/